# Unable to change background image for specific section in HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I am fairly new to HTML & CSS. I recently downloaded a theme from bootstrap and I am trying to change the background image of a section/div.Not only have I tried adding code to CSS, but I have also included the background image reference inline with my html code. But I am still not able to change the background. The image is a .jpg.

Here is the HTML Code for the specific section:

```
<!-- About Section -->
<section class="success" id="about" style="background-image:parallax.jpg;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1>About</h1>
               <!-- <img class="img-responsive" src="new.gif" alt="" align="middle" align ="center" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto"> -->
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p align="left" style="font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;" > Hello.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                <a href="Website Resume.pdf" class="btn  btn-outline" style="font-family:'Shadows Into Light', cursive;">
                    <i style="font-family:'Shadows Into Light', cursive; text-align: center;"></i> Check Out My Resume!
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is the CSS Code :

```
section.success {
    color: #000000;
    background: #ffffff;
}

#about{
    background-image: url("parallax.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 300%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Where is the image stored in relation to your HTML and CSS files? Do you see any 404 errors in your console?

Comment: Hi ! I don't see any 404 errors. The images are in the same folder as the index.html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the inline CSS you wrote in your HTML is not valid, it should be:

`background-image: url("parallax.jpg");`

As well, the CSS you wrote in your stylesheet is not valid, it should be :

```
background-image: url("parallax.jpg") !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

Or

```
background: transparent url("parallax.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center !important;
background-size: cover;
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score 0):

Your first example should be...

`style="background-image: url(parallax.jpg);"`

Assuming your CSS file is in the root, your code should be...

`background: url(parallax.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

Your background may be getting overridden somewhere else. To force the image add !important to the style. Change the CSS to this...

```
background: transparent url("parallax.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center !impotant;
background-size: cover !impotant;
```

This tells the browser to use this over any other declaration which might come after it.